# Class.forName() - JDK7 - ClassNotFoundException

Tags: java, intellij-idea, classpath

I can't get this to work!

I found lots of those problems on stackoverflow but 90% of the problems were related to the missing package name, but I don't have any package, it's "unnamed" therefore must not be defined within `forName()` parameter.

> A class that is not in a named package is in an unnamed package. Thus the full class name is "Main".
>   Such classes cannot be used from a named package, except via reflection.

The other solution was specifying classpath, however src (blue folder) IS a classpath as said here

> You can right click on any directory in your IntelliJ project, select "Mark Directory As...", and choose "Source Root". That director folder will change color from yellow to blue; IntelliJ considers all those directories to be in your CLASSPATH.

[image]

Yet it's still not working! It slowly drives me nuts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This message means that you need to handle the checked exception, that is, `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException`. It doesn't mean you couldn't find/load this class.

In order to handle checked exception, you can

1. Wrap the codes with `try {...} catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {...}`.
2. Add it to throw declaration of `main` method: `main(String[] args) throws ClassNotFoundException`.

In IDEA, you can always use <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>enter</kbd> to see suggestions.
[image]